# Refresh All Queries and Connections of an Excel Workbook (Excel Online) using Office Scripts and Power Automate

Tags: powerquery, power-automate, office-scripts

I started using the new Office Scripts in Excel on the web. I was wondering if anyone knows if it´s possible to Refresh the Queries and Connections of an Excel Workbook saved on SharePoint Online.

I would like to run the script utilizing a Scheduled Flow in Power Automate.

There seems to be a workbook.refreshAllDataConnections() Method in typescript (when writing in the Script Editor) but it doesn´t really do anything.

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The Power Query refresh is not supported for the time being. Regarding other types of connections, it is not yet detailed out in the API. There's a docs bug open to get clarification on what types of connections are supported.

Docs bug: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-reference/issues/805

Comment: Just to add on here, there is a Power Query connector—if you're able to accomplish your scenario with the connections made in Power Automate instead of Excel, this should be achievable.

Comment: @DanielG.Wilson's comment got me excited about the possibility of a Power Query connector, but it is currently only available as a premium connector to SQL Server [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/#transform-data-using-power-query)

Comment: Ahhh @Cory, you're totally right—apologies